# My blog only allow image uploads, I need help to allow upload Videos

Tags: php, image, blogs

I am completely new to PHP but have managed to have a function which allows me to upload images as part of a blog entry. The problem is i am trying to make this also allow video upload. I have tried everything and I still cannot get my head around it. Here is my present code, any help will be appreciated

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="card m-b-20">
    <div class="card-block">
    <div class="m-t-20">
    <h6 class="text-muted"><b>Title</b></h6>
    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" />
    </di>
    <div class="m-t-20">
    <h6 class="text-muted"><b>Blog Image</b></h6>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" />
    </di>
    <div class="m-t-20">
    <h6 class="text-muted"><b>Content</b></h6>
    <p class="text-muted m-b-15 font-13">
    <textarea class="summernote" name="message"></textarea>
    </div?
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
include_once '../config/dbConfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))

{

    $title = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['title']);

    $info = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

    $slug = wordwrap(strtolower($title), 1, '-', 0);

    date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos"); 

    $d=date('Y-m-d');

     $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
     $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

     $folder="../assets/img/slider/";

    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    $pix = $d . '_' . rand(1000,100000). '.' . end($temp);

    $target_file = $folder . $pix;

 $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO blog (`title`, `slug`, `content`, `image`, `date`) VALUES ('$title', '$slug', '$info', '$pix', '$d')");    

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

    if (isset($query_new_m)){
     ?>
```

Comment: nothing in the code posted restricts file type

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. That's why I am tearing my hair out as I cannot seem to see why its not working for me

Comment: When i upload a video, it is not reflecting in the database at all

Comment: then the porblem is in other code, not psychic

Comment: you can look at the maximum file size config. maybe the video is over the limit that's why its not continuing to save in your database.